# How to login to different user in RDP locked system

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I am having two systems with Windows 10 OS namely comp1 and comp2.
In comp1 system, I has two user accounts namely user1 and user2.

From comp2 system, I have taken the comp1 as Remote desktop connection using user1 login. Immediately comp1 system got locked. Now in comp1 system, I tried to login to user2 account. But it throws error message that the remote desktop connection will be disconnected if i do so.

Is it possible to login to one user account if the other user account was locked for remote desktop? I don't want to use remote assistance option.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want this for my personal use. Even I  have tried TeamViewer but its not giving what i expect...

Comment: Why do you want to be running both sessions at once? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Two users want to use the same system at a time. So if i do requested option, then I can make two users to work at a time.

Comment: This can't be done with RDP, and probably not at all with a desktop Windows. You'd probably need a server OS, and Windows Terminal Server.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin is correct. Windows client SKUs (home, pro, enterprise) only support a single session. Windows Server Datacenter supports multiple sessions and could achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop versions of Windows do not support multiple simultaneous logons. If you were to try to do this with RDP, an attempt to connect via RDP would cause any other RDP user or the console user to be signalled for permission to disconnect to allow the new RDP user access to the computer.

Server versions of Windows that support Terminal Server can do what you describe.

Comment: It's a money-saving strategy for small business end users to run very cheap thin client PCs, but do important work inside an RDP session on a more expensive powerful server.  Microsoft wants to charge for the ability to do that, so it's only available in the more expensive Windows Server OSes.